# Creating a menu with 'ul'

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to create a menu with the list 'ul'.
The problem I´m facing is:

The submenu doesn´t appear at the top of its corresponding menu link, but, below.

You can see it at this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/6r6e8/

Thanks.

Comment: You might find Suckerfish as a useful starting point for building a menu like this: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/. Often, it can be done with little or no script, just CSS.

Comment: When you say below do you mean literally vertically below. Or do you mean you want it to appear as it does now but in line with the menu item horizontally than a bit underneath it.

Comment: I mean literally vertically below. 
I want the submenu links to appear at the same horizontal line as its menu link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including a top value in your CSS:

```
ul.menu ul {
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Good call.  Much better than margin-top.

Answer (score -1):

You could add `margin-top: -21px` to your `ul.menu ul styles` as a quick fix.